# Fetch data in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fetch

Is there an iOS function that would allow an application to "fetch" data even when the application isn't currently running?  I'm looking for something similar to the email settings where you can choose "fetch" and a frequency (like every 15 or 30 mins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No email is apple's default app. So it is supported. I dont think so it is possible. 
You need to apply some trick for it, but without user interaction, no, it is against apple's privacy policy

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, Apple introduced a feature called "Background App Refresh" that allows apps to refresh their content in the background.

Below is a good tutorial:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch/